# Is there any option to encrypt code in java and it should be decrypt and execute only runtime?

Tags: java, security, encryption

I want to develop code for which business logic should not open and I tried encapsulation and RMI to keep code at the secure end but anybody can get that using Reflection. Is there any possibilities?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: You can try obfuscator, check https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/

Comment: There are no possibilities that will defend you against someone with moderate "hacking" skills and sufficient time and motivation.

Comment: The only way you can keep your code private is to keep it only on your own machines (i.e. not distribute the software, but provide it "as a service").

Comment: @Thilo but we have to provide solutions to client for offline also as nowadays no one wants to share data on the cloud with others they want their own environment they demand to give all permission of server else we will secure by permission. So that's why I am looking for it.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam that one which is provided by you is used for clean up code, not for security.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to read an encoded .class file and then load it using a custom class loader

```
    byte[] bytes = // read from encoded file and decode
    ClassLoader cl = new ClassLoader() {
        @Override
        public Class<?> loadClass(String name) {
            try {
                return super.loadClass(name);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                return defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            }
        }
    };

    Class clazz = cl.loadClass("my.Decoded");
    Object o = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
    Method action = clazz.getMethod("action");
    action.invoke(o);
```

Comment: what content should be there in "defineClass" method?

Comment: It is a protected ClassLoader#defineClass method. Youd don't need to write your own. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass-java.lang.String-byte:A-int-int-